# Curious to know How Tor works?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I am very curious to know about Working of Tor. Please tell me how Tor works ? I am using Tor Browser Bundle.

I want to know that is there any other Service/ Software similar to Tor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in laymen's terms this is how Tor works.

Think of a shopping mall that has multiple entrances and multiple exits.  You choose a random entrance, and then walk a long random path through the mall mixing with people, where your arrive at an exit.

This is an analogy for how Tor works.  Your computer accesses and entrance node (the mall entrance).  Then go through middle link where the entrance node's identity is mixed (walking around the mall and mixing with the people).  Finally your data exits and reaches its destination (exiting the mall).

Hidden services kinda work like this.  So lets say you want to meet this shady dude.  He and you talk, and set a rendezvous point inside the mall to meet at.  You both enter the mall, and mix your traffic for a while, until you meet at the point and start talking.

Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Interesting analogy.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to following to know about working of Tor:
https://www.torproject.org/about/overview.html.en